# IPCONFIG find ETHERNET ADAPTER working, how do I find Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I found a script that changes my DNS addresses, but I can only get it to work on my ethernet adapter. How would I go about changing this on my wireless adapter?

```
 SET adapterName=
 FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"') DO (
  SET adapterName=%%a
  SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
  SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
  netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" static 172.16.0.1 primary
  netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" 172.16.0.2 index=2
 )
```

The above works for changing ethernet. I've tried the following for wireless with no luck,

```
 FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "WIRELESS LAN ADAPTER"') DO (
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried "WIRELESS LAN ADAPTER WI-FI" instead "ETHERNET ADAPTER" and found my wi-fi adapter

Comment: It worked, it just pulls up the adapter, but I'm still missing something. In the other code it had a line for SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17! and SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!

I assume to edit the name so it could then be changed, any idea what rules should I apply to Wireless Lan that should be different in order for it to allow me to reference it?

Comment: Well, I dont know if this helps, but here is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/rename-netadapter?view=win10-ps
You can use Rename-NetAdapter command to edit the name..

Maybe I didn't realize what you really want to do

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help! I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt,

```
IPCONFIG | FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER ETHERNET"
```

returns,

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
```

and

```
IPCONFIG | FIND /I "WIRELESS LAN ADAPTER WI-FI"
```

returns,

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
```

The following lines remove the first 17 characters plus the : from the end of "Ethernet Adapter Ethernet:", turning it into "Ethernet"

```
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
```

I just needed to do the same for Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:, but the first 21 characters

```
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~21!
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
```